Upgrading from Angular 17.1 to 18.2 results in Internal Server Error in Docker container
My Angular app currently uses v17.1, running as expected. Now that Angular 18 has been out for a few months I'd like to explore an upgrade to v18.2.
I ran the following commands
ng update @angular/core@18 @angular/cli@18
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli @angular-eslint/schematics
ng update @angular/cdk@17
ng update @angular/cdk@18

Which results in these versions:
Angular CLI: 18.2.0
Node: 20.11.1
Package Manager: npm 10.2.4
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 18.2.0
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1802.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   18.2.0
@angular-devkit/core            18.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      18.2.0
@schematics/angular             18.2.0
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      5.4.5
zone.js                         0.14.10

After a few manual fixes, I can run the app perfectly using ng serve (http://localhost:4200/). However, when I run npm run build my /dist/browser folder contains a bunch more css.map files. Additionally, after building my app using Docker, I get an Internal Server Error when trying to load the app via the Docker port (http://localhost:9992/). Note that the Dockerfile has not changed. If I swap back to our develop branch and rebuild, I can load the app from within Docker as expected.
What in Angular has changed that could cause this issue?
